# Странная запись обрезанных фото в imwrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Не понимаю, почему но на некотрых фотографиях при сохранении часть фото заменяется тем, что находится правее, но на том же уровне по высоте? (Сложно это объяснить по этому прикреплю фото)
Если есть какие то идеи почему это происходит или как это исправить - буду благодарен. Происходит это не постоянно и без какой либо регулярности. И у меня абсолютно никаких идей почему это происходит...

[image: Лишняя часть]

Это часть кода который отвечает за сохранение миниатюр фотографий лиц.

```
for k, d in enumerate(faces):
    if count < 6:
        self.current_frame_face_position_list.append(tuple(
        [faces[k].left(), int(faces[k].bottom() + (faces[k].bottom() - faces[k].top()) / 4)]))
        self.current_frame_centroid_list.append(
        [int(faces[k].left() + faces[k].right()) / 2,
         int(faces[k].top() + faces[k].bottom()) / 2])
    
    #  Compute the size of rectangle box
        height = (d.bottom() - d.top())
        width = (d.right() - d.left())
        hh = int(height / 2)
        ww = int(width / 2)
        try:
            cv2.rectangle(resize,
                          tuple([d.left() - ww, d.top() - hh]),
                          tuple([d.right() + ww, d.bottom() + hh]),
                          (255, 255, 255), 2) 
            img_rr = np.zeros((int(height*2), width*2, 3), np.uint8)
            for ii in range(height*2):
                    for jj in range(width*2):
                        img_rr[ii][jj] = resize[d.top()-hh + ii][d.left()-ww + jj] 
        except IndexError:
            print("Out of bounds")
        written = cv2.imwrite(inputguest + "/" + str(st) + "-" + str(count) + " frame.jpg", img_rr)
        print("output", written, st)
    else:
        pass
        print("Больше 5 кадров")
```

Comment: 2 вопроса: вы уверены, что ошибка в этом куске коды, а не раньше? И вы уверены, что не выходите за пределы вашей матрицы при таких операциях: `img_rr[ii][jj] = resize[d.top()-hh + ii][d.left()-ww + jj]`?

Comment: Во всяком случае с большинством фото это работает. Такие кадры проскакивают иногда. Не уверен на 100% что именно здесь, но если я сам понимаю что написал то здесь определяется какую часть от всего кадра нужно записать.

Comment: Вы можете ответить на мои два вопроса?